# How to update InnoDB Table Statistics Manually even if user doesn't have enough privielege

Tags: mysql

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/09/11/updating-innodb-table-statistics-manually/

Currently the users do not have sufficient permissions to query or update the mysql.innodb_index_stats table. how to proceed with this finding.

Comment: Ask the system admin to give you the required permissions you need to do your job. If you are on shared/managed hosting, you may need to upgrade your hosting plan.

Comment: users are restricted with the privileges. what is the option if still I need to update the innodb stats manually.

Comment: If you do not have the permissions to do it, you can't, at least not without doing something that might get you fired, sued, or your hosting contract canceled. The admin will be able to give you the permissions. If that is not possible, you may want to change your question and ask for a different way to solve your problem (e.g. using `force index` to make mysql use a specific index, which may be what you are trying to do by manipulating the statistics which have influence on which index mysql chooses).